# Is it possible to remove a style based on the state of a sibling div's button?

Tags: css, sass

I have an html snippet that will hide a button when clicked:

```
<div class="item">
    Some Text
 </div>
 <div>
    <button onclick="hideButton()">
      Hide me
    </button> 
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,black,white);
}
```

Using CSS, is it possible to remove the background-image style on div.item if the button nested in the sibling div is in the hidden state? I know how this can be done in JavaScript, but curious if this can be handled solely with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the newly added CSS `has` selector: `div:has(> button:active) ~ .item` This is not widely supported at the moment, so JavaScript might be what you need here.

Comment: Clicking a button doesn’t make it active forever

Comment: Yeah I think browsers like FF are still lagging behind, would love to use :has()

Comment: @nicael That was an example, if the toggle functionality is needed, a styled checkbox input will do just fine